# How to optimize this code for speed and get rid of the nested loop?

Tags: c++, loops

I was trying to solve [This problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/706/B), but I keep getting Time limit exceeded, when the input is 100000.
I need to optimize the nested loop somehow.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[100000];
    int n, x, q, m;
    cin >> n; //number of shops that sell the drink
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> x; //prices of each drink in the shop
        arr[i] = x; //add it to the array
    }  
 
    cin >> q; //number of days
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        cin >> m; // money the person will be able to spend on each day
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (m >= arr[j]){ //if the amount of money is more or equal
            // to the price of bottle, increase counter
           // (number of shop we can buy from)
                count++;
            }
        }
        cout << count << '\n'; //the number of shops the person can buy drinks in with his money
    }
}
```

I even tried another approach with sort and upper bound but still TLE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[200000];
    int n, x, q, m;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> x;
        arr[i] = x;
    }  
 
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        cin >> m;
        int count = 0;
        //sort the array
        sort(arr, arr + n);
        //find the upper bound
        int upper1 = upper_bound(arr, arr + n, m) - arr;
        cout << upper1 << '\n';
    }
}
```

link to my FIRST solution after submission [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/706/submission/182181841)

link to my SECOND solution after submission [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/706/submission/182186416)

Comment: Please don't write questions that are incomprehensible without following external links. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @NathanPierson I tried to add little comments, hope this helps as I can't explain the whole problem in here

Comment: If you receive a time limit exceeded in a coding challenge, it in 99% of the time means you should use a different algorithm/approach.

Comment: There is a "Tutorial" button in the right-bottom corner of the page, in the "Contest materials" section.

Comment: Right now your algorithm is O(n * q). Assuming q is comparable to n, you could improve that pretty substantially to O(n log n + q log n) by sorting `arr` first and then doing a binary search to figure out how many shops you can buy from.

Comment: @user4581301 No doubt. And these algorithmic challenges do not touch, like, 95% of the language and 100% of external libraries. Still, a way to practice writing for loops in the very beginning, and a fun sports afterwards if one wants to proceed.

Comment: Instead of using cin it would be faster to put the data in a file and use ifstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually appears that your second solution CAN be optimized, by sorting your `arr` only once, before going into a loop.